# Pandas crosstab how can i get two values of mean aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my problem. Suppose I have

```
df = ({'DAY':['20210101','20210102','20210102'],'TTM':[0.1,0.1,0.5],'TTS':[0.3,0.4,0.4] })
```

I want to get a CROSSTAB that calculates the mean of TTM and TTS group by DAY, like this

```
DAY      |meanTTM |MeanTTS
20210101 | 0.1    |0.3
20210102 | 0.3    | 0.4
```

I tried

```
pd.crosstab(index=data3['DAY'],columns=df['DAY'],values=df['TPS_ATTENTE','TPS_GEN_ACK'],margins=False,aggfunc='mean')
```

But I don't get any result, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
out = df.groupby('DAY')[['TTM','TTS']].mean().add_prefix('mean').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        DAY  meanTTM  meanTTS
0  20210101      0.1      0.3
1  20210102      0.3      0.4
```

Comment: it worked fine , thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='DAY')
```

The default aggregation function is `mean` but this can be changed with the `aggfunc` parameter.